# Looping Multiple Arrays by year

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm looking multiple arrays but having trouble with aligning them in a table based on year. At the moment the data doesn't line up with the corresponding year, if data exists in any year it just places the data at the first row, then places '0' data for the rest, ie. not aligning with the year.

View

```
<table>
<% @a.zip(@b, @c, @d) do |a, b, c, d| %>
 <tr>
  <td><%= a.year %></td>
  <% if a.blank? %>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>0</td>
  <% else %>
    <td><%= a.id %></td>
    <td><%= a.data %></td>
  <% end %>
  <% if b.blank? %>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>0</td>
  <% else %>
    <td><%= b.id %></td>
    <td><%= b.data %></td>
  <% end %>
  <% if c.blank? %>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>0</td>
  <% else %>
    <td><%= c.id %></td>
    <td><%= c.data %></td>
  <% end %>
  <% if d.blank? %>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>0</td>
  <% else %>
    <td><%= d.id %></td>
    <td><%= d.data %></td>
  <% end %>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Controller

```
@a = Result.where(id: params[:id_select]).group('year').where('data > 0').select('AVG(data) AS data, year as year, COUNT(id) AS id').order('year ASC')

@b = Result.where(id: params[:id_select]).group('year').where('data > 0').select('AVG(data) AS data, year as year, COUNT(id) AS id').where('id = ?', '0').order('year ASC')

@c = Result.where(id: params[:id_select]).group('year').where('data > 0').select('AVG(data) AS data, year as year, COUNT(id) AS id').where('id = ?', '1').order('year ASC')

@d = Result.where(id: params[:id_select]).group('year').where('data > 0').select('AVG(data) AS data, year as year, COUNT(id) AS id').where('id = ?', '2').order('year ASC')
```

Comment: Kindly mention data format in your table and output format you want.

Comment: i have some troubles getting what the question wants, can you write down the data you have explicitly **not the queries** and the format you want in text.

Comment: @DollarChills, I've proposed a solution to your problem below. I hope I get it right. Let me know if it suits your needs.

Comment: Did you try to get all the Result (whatever the year is) in SQL and then do a `results.group_by(&:year)`? It will group results in a hash where the key is the year and the value is an array containing every Result matching this year.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can try this way. in this you have not need to check for blank values. i hope @a contains all your available years otherwise you needs to merge all years an loop through years

```
<table>
<% @a.each do |a| %>
 <tr>
  <td><%= a.year %></td>
    <td><%= (a.id || 0 rescue 0) %></td>
    <td><%= (a.data || 0 rescue 0) %></td>
    <td><%= (@b.select{|h| h if h["year"] == a.year }.first.id || 0 rescue 0) %></td>
    <td><%= (@b.select{|h| h if h["year"] == a.year }.first.data || 0 rescue 0 ) %></td>
    <td><%= (@c.select{|h| h if h["year"] == a.year }.first.id || 0 rescue 0) %></td>
    <td><%= (@c.select{|h| h if h["year"] == a.year }.first.data || 0 rescue 0) %></td>
    <td><%= (@d.select{|h| h if h["year"] == a.year }.first.id || 0 rescue 0) %></td>
    <td><%= (@d.select{|h| h if h["year"] == a.year }.first.data || 0 rescue 0) %></td>
 </tr>
<% end %>
</table>
```

If your @a not contains all years then just try to merge it by

```
years = ((@a.collect{|h| h["year"]}) + (@b.collect{|h| h["year"]}) + (@c.collect{|h| h["year"]}) + (@d.collect{|h| h["year"]})).uniq
```

then you can just looping through years array as:

```
<% years.each do |year| %>
     <tr>
      <td><%= year %></td>
        <td><%= (@a.select{|h| h if h["year"] == year }.first.id || 0 rescue 0) %></td>
        <td><%= (@a.select{|h| h if h["year"] ==  year }.first.data || 0 rescue 0 ) %></td>
        <td><%= (@b.select{|h| h if h["year"] == year }.first.id || 0 rescue 0) %></td>
        <td><%= (@b.select{|h| h if h["year"] ==  year }.first.data || 0 rescue 0 ) %></td>
        <td><%= (@c.select{|h| h if h["year"] == year }.first.id || 0 rescue 0) %></td>
        <td><%= (@c.select{|h| h if h["year"] == year }.first.data || 0 rescue 0) %></td>
        <td><%= (@d.select{|h| h if h["year"] == year }.first.id || 0 rescue 0) %></td>
        <td><%= (@d.select{|h| h if h["year"] == year }.first.data || 0 rescue 0) %></td>
     </tr>
    <% end %>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably mean this in your view:

```
<%
  A = @a.group_by{|a| a.year}
  B = @b.group_by{|b| b.year}
  C = @c.group_by{|c| c.year}
  D = @d.group_by{|d| d.year}
%>

<table>
  <% A.each do |year, a| %>
    <% b = B[year] %>
    <% c = C[year] %>
    <% d = D[year] %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= year %></td>
      <% if a.blank? %>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>0</td>
      <% else %>
        <%= a.id %>
        <%= a.data %>
      <% end %>
      <% if b.blank? %>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>0</td>
      <% else %>
        <td><%= b.id %></td>
        <td><%= b.data %></td>
      <% end %>
      <% if c.blank? %>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>0</td>
      <% else %>
        <td><%= c.id %></td>
        <td><%= c.data %></td>
      <% end %>
      <% if d.blank? %>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>0</td>
      <% else %>
        <td><%= d.id %></td>
        <td><%= d.data %></td>
      <% end %>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
</table>
```

I assume here `@a` contains all the years other arrays may contain (based on query). If it's not the case, then you first need to create full array of years:

```
<% years = (A.keys + B.keys + C.keys + D.keys).uniq %>
<table>
  <% years.each do |year| %>
    <% a = A[year] %>
    <!-- the rest is the same, as above -->
  <% end %>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks Dimakura, I have tried this method and no luck. I'm already grouping by year in the controller.

Comment: I get undefined method `id' where 'b.id' starts.

Comment: @DollarChills can you show me what is or how you get those arrays

Comment: I get them via a simple form which has a few options as a drop down.

Comment: You have formulas for `@a`, `@b` etc. Are they still valid?

Comment: Looks like `b` is not an `ActiveRecord` instance. Can you give an output `@a.inspect`

Answer (score 1):

In the controller:

```
@results_by_year = Result.where(your_conditions).group_by(&:year)
# this retrieves all the Result records wanted, without taking care of the record's `year`
```

The hash's structure will be like this:

```
# { 2010: [<Result id:1>, <Result id:3>], 
#   2012: [<Result id:2>], 
#   2014: [<Result id:7>, <Result id:9>] }
```

In the view:

```
@results_by_year.each do |year, results|
  = year
  - results.each do |result|
    = result.id
    = result.data
end
```